# How can I make the 'pointermove' event keep firing after closing a dialog element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make something that allows the user to drag elements from a modal dialog and place them on the page.
So I call `dialog.close()` once the user starts dragging. This works fine on desktop, but on touch devices, the 'pointermove' event is not firing.

See the snipped below for an example:

```js
dialog.showModal();

button.addEventListener("pointerdown", () => {
    dialog.close();
});

container.addEventListener("pointermove", () => {
    console.log("move");
});
```

```css
html, body, dialog, #container, #button {
  touch-action: none;
}

#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
</div>

<dialog id="dialog">
  Emulate a touch device using devtools and drag the green square to the red square.
  <div id="button">
  
  </div>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use [Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to reuse the same code for both desktop and mobile. Actually I got it to work somehow in my actual project by adding `touch-action: none;` to my element. But I'm not sure why that's not working in the example snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing a "drag and drop" functionality on touch devices, you'll be facing two problems:

#### Direct manipulation devices cause implicit pointer capture

Devices which let the user pan and zoom the screen by touching it are classified as "direct manipulation" devices. Pointer events originating from such devices are subject to [implicit pointer capture](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents3/#dfn-implicit-pointer-capture), which means that all subsequent events are limited to the element that caught the initial `pointerdown` event.

> 9.4 Implicit pointer capture
>
> Inputs that implement direct manipulation interactions for panning and zooming (such as touch or stylus on a touchscreen) SHOULD behave exactly as if setPointerCapture() was called on the target element just before the invocation of any pointerdown listeners.

To get around this limitation and to let the red square receive pointer events originating from the green square, you may call `releasePointerCapture`:

```js
button.addEventListener("pointerdown", event => {
    dialog.close();
    event.target.releasePointerCapture(event.pointerId);
});
```

#### Panning suppresses pointer events

Direct manipulation devices rely on the user dragging their finger across the screen to pan (or scroll) the page. Without `touch-action: none`, you'll find that as soon as the dialog closes, moving your finger causes the page to scroll, which [prevents the `pointermove` event from firing](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents3/#suppressing-a-pointer-event-stream):

> 4.1.3.3 Suppressing a pointer event stream
>
> The user agent MUST suppress a pointer event stream when it detects that a pointer is unlikely to continue to produce events. Any of the following scenarios satisfy this condition (there MAY be additional scenarios):
>
> - The pointer is subsequently used by the user agent to manipulate the page viewport (e.g. panning or zooming).

A solution to this, as you have found, is to use `touch-action`, which prevents panning or zooming if the gesture originates from the affected elements:

```css
#button {
    touch-action: none;
}
```

**Do not** set `touch-action` to `none` on all the elements in the document, as that will prevent your user from scrolling the page, rendering it unusable.

Comment: Thanks! `releasePointerCapture` seems to do the trick for me!